# Symfony Deploy to Apache Server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

The Steps I have done as I understood:

1. add symfony/apache-pack which generates a .htaccess file under public folder.
2. Add The Prod Environment and Clear Cache. Also replaced the database as needed.
3. Then I put the .htaccess file into the the root folder of xampp.

I am using linux and the path of the  symfony is htdocs/suite

The htdocs file was under the suite/public folder and I moved that to the suite folder. I marged it with the docs of symfony official page

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#adding-rewrite-rules

My .htaccess of suite folder is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # ...
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/suite/public

    <Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/suite/public>
        AllowOverride None

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]


    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now It is saying:

> Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
> your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in
> a CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
> Error 500 localhost Apache/2.4.51 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1l PHP/8.0.11
> mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.1

Comment: You can check the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (might be located different with your setup)

Comment: Don't know if it's related. But check your tab-indenting with the contents you've copied from the `.htaccess` file.  Also make sure, because you've copy pasted the content from `.htaccess` to the virtualhost that you remove the `.htaccess` file. It's faster since the config is already loaded into the virtualhost

Comment: So what should i do now please? I wanted to deploy symfony app but it is showing server error.

Comment: "Then I put the .htaccess file into the the root folder of xampp." The .htaccess created by apache-pack?

Comment: Yes. It is working. I was using symfony 5.3 but the . htaccess was not working in xampp but it is working into my host server. Thank you for your help.